# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Python but a Key Error is received when using a different graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, dijkstra

I'm a university student and we were tasked to implement Dijkstra's algorithm on the given graph below.
[Graph to implement Dijkstra's algorithm on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmLW.png)

We were given a code to use and/or modify and help answer the question given.

```
import heapq
import math

def dijkstra(G, S):
    pq = []
    entry_finder = {}
    costs = {}
    pred = {S: None}
    REMOVED = 'removed'

    def add_entry(label, priority):
        if label in entry_finder:
            remove_entry(label)
        entry = [priority, label]
        entry_finder[label] = entry
        heapq.heappush(pq, entry)

    def remove_entry(label):
        entry = entry_finder.pop(label)
        entry[-1] = REMOVED

    def pop_entry():
        while pq:
            priority, label = heapq.heappop(pq)
            if label != REMOVED:
                del entry_finder[label]
                return priority, label
        return None, None

    for v in G:
        if v == S:
            add_entry(S, 0)
        else:
            add_entry(v, math.inf)
    while pq:
        d_u, u = pop_entry()
        if u is not None and u != REMOVED:
            costs[u] = d_u
            for e in G[u]:
                v, w = e
                entry_v = entry_finder[v]
                d_v = entry_v[0]
                if d_v > d_u + w:
                    add_entry(v, d_u + w)
                    pred[v] = u
return costs, pred
```

This code was shown to work for a separate graph that was used in an example from our lectures. The graph was converted into code as such.

```
G = {
    '0': [('1', 2), ('2', 6), ('3', 7)],
    '1': [('3', 3), ('4', 6)],
    '2': [('4', 1)],
    '3': [('4', 5)],
    '4': []
}

costs, pred = dijkstra(G, '0')
print(costs, pred)
```

So I know for a fact that the given code works. The problem arose when I tried to implement the graph into code and it gave me a KeyError: 'D'. My implementation of the graph is as follows.

```
G = {
    'A': [('B', 56), ('C', 96), ('D', 78)],
    'B': [('D', 18), ('F', 208), ('E', 110)],
    'C': [('D', 20), ('F', 90)],
    'D': [('F', 112)],
    'E': [('F', 16), ('G', 46), ('I', 108)],
    'F': [('G', 20), ('H', 62)],
    'G': [('H', 40)],
    'H': [('I', 29), ('J', 56)],
    'I': [('J', 21)],
    'J': []
}
costs, pred = dijkstra(G, 'A')
print(costs, pred)
```

The error also comes with:
line 41, in dijkstra
entry_v = entry_finder[v]. I'd like to know if the error came from my wrong implementation of the graph or if the given sample code itself had errors.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use `print()` to display which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. You should see for what values it gives you error and then you may try to solve it.

Comment: I don't remeber how works `Dijkstra's algorithm` but if I remove `del entry_finder[label]` then at least code works without error - but I can't confirm if it still will gives correct results.